# Is it ok if my transferred wort has some undissolved hops in it?

Tags: wort, primary-fermentation

Today I brewed my first 5 gallon batch. A pumpkin ale! Super stoked, but it was hard to avoid getting some of the undissolved hops in it as I transferred the force chilled wort to the primary fermenter with a siphon. Will that affect my primary fermentation? I originally just wanted to do a primary even though it calls for a secondary because the brewer thought it was too pumpkin pie-ish. But, if I need to transfer it anyways to make it cleaner I will.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fine.  I don't think it will affect your primary fermentation to any noticeable degree as far as homebrewing is concerned.  You'll need to siphon again to bottle or keg.  You can also use cheesecloth or a nylon bag to hop with to keep this to a minimum.   I'd love to see your recipe, I'm big on pumpkin beers too.... tis the season!

Comment: Jeff, I basically followed a YouTube video. But here is the recipe:  7 pounds of pale malt extract, 1 pound of maris otter, .5 lbs of Munich, 1oz of fuggle hops. Bake about 3 pounds of baked pumpkin cut into 1 inch cubes. After seeping the maris otter and Munich in one gallon of 150 degree water, add it to the 5 gallon of boiling water with the malt extract, pumpkin and hops. Boil 60 minutes. At flame out add a handful of pumpkin spice. Pitch Safale-US-05. After a week of fermenting, bake 3 more pounds of pumpkin, half way through adding 4oz of molasses and 4oz maple syrup.

Answer (score 1):

Hops don't dissolve. They basically come in 3 forms (whole, pellet and extract which is very rare for homebrewers).  The whole hops are easy to spot (they'll be those leaves floating on top of your wort). Pelletized hops break up and are normally found in the bottom of your boil kettle.  If they make it into your fermenter, it's not a problem.  Heck, you can even drop and once or seven into your secondary (this practice is called "dry hopping" and it's common with IPAs).

Comment: Jeff, I basically followed a YouTube video. But here is the recipe:

Comment: Add the pumpkin baked with molasses and syrup to second fermenter, siphon to second fermenter. One more week of fermenting, then bottle, two weeks of bottling with carbonation obviously. And that's it.